# Raspberry PI HMI

Tags: pi-3, gui, software-recommendation, web-interface, modbus

Is it possible to make a Raspberry Pi 3 into a functional HMI for an instrument or set of PLC devices(I usually control remote devices through TCP unless I build the HMI into the unit's case)? I would want an interactive GUI interface, which I know would require some programming, but I was wondering if this has been done before or if there is a OS/Software that already does this as well. I've looked around and seen that modbus communication is possible but have not seen where someone has used a Pi as a HMI or Controller interface. I am mainly looking for alternatives to the expensive HMI I am currently using.

Comment: For the question you are asking, the answer is Yes. But as far as how difficult it will be, it all depends on your programing ability and what your actually trying to control. But yes, you can put a touchscreen or other interface on the pi and control other stuff with it....

Comment: Doing some research it looks like using AdvancedHMI would be a good option. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Please take a look at the help section on asking good questions.   https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask    This is not a place for discussions or asking about peoples experience. Go out and give it a try, if you get stuck with a specific question regarding your project that can be answered, please come back and ask a new question

Comment: So you want to make an *Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager* to observe the *Portevin–Le Chatelier effect* controlling it through *Transformer coupled plasma*?